# back substitution in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm supposed to implement a back substitution. We receive the row echelon matrix A, the vector b and the solution vector x has already been initialized.

I have a problem with the indices in my code. No matter how I adjust my range I always seem to fall out right in the beginning and get an out of bounds error. I already tested my solution on paper and it should be doing the right thing, however, I just can't get past the index problem. Does anyone have any clues?

```
def back_substitution(A: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = len(b)

    if A[n-1][n-1] == 0:
        raise ValueError

    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        x[i] = A[i][i]/b[i]
        for j in range (i-1, 0, -1):
            A[i][i] += A[j][i]*x[i]

    return x

x = np.zeros(1)
M = np.matrix([[1, -1, 2], [0, -1, -2], [0, 0, -6]])
c = np.matrix([[0],[0],[3]])
back_substitution(M,c)
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 167, in <module>
    back_substitution(M,c)
  File "main.py", line 125, in back_substitution
    x[i] = A[i][i]/b[i]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 284, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_triangular.html

Answer (score 2):

You are using list indexing but arrays are indexed with a two item array. And you don't define `x`  inside the function so it is picking up the one you defined outside the function def and tripping up. Because that's a single element array.

Please don't use `np.matrix` anymore it is deprecated.

```
def back_substitution(A: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = b.size
    x = np.zeros_like(b)

    if A[n-1, n-1] == 0:
        raise ValueError

    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        x[i] = A[i, i]/b[i]
        for j in range (i-1, 0, -1):
            A[i, i] += A[j, i]*x[i]

    return x

x = np.zeros(1)
M = np.matrix([[1, -1, 2], [0, -1, -2], [0, 0, -6]])
c = np.matrix([[0],[0],[3]])
back_substitution(M,c)
```

Comment: Sorry, I definitely defined and filled x with zeros in my function, just forgot to put it in the proper place after my edit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following code is correct. Please check this out.

```
def back_substitution(A: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = b.size
    x = np.zeros_like(b)

    if A[n-1, n-1] == 0:
        raise ValueError


    x[n-1] = b[n-1]/A[n-1, n-1]
    C = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        bb = 0
        for j in range (i+1, n):
            bb += A[i, j]*x[j]

        C[i, i] = b[i] - bb
        x[i] = C[i, i]/A[i, i]

    return x
```